# payment gateway integration

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, payment

I want to make an application in which I can integrate the payment gateway like authorized.net, Paypal, etc. but as per Apple guide line the using third party payment gateway other then InApp purchase will be rejected. So how to make such an application?

Sunil Chavda

Comment: Um, if you know it is going to be rejected, why do you want to know how to make one?

Comment: I think he wants to know how to do it without getting rejected.  In other words, 'I know it's against the rules, so how do I get it OK'd anyway?'

Comment: Wouldn't it be in Apple's best interest to have you use their payment gateway, so that they can take a cut? I guess you could write an app that is only for jail-broken iPhones and sell it through other channels.  Don't expect many users, though.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, you don't.  The rules are the rules.